# HTML/CSS Div container showing side borders

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me where these side lines originate from?
[image: side lines]

It's only showing on that DIV and this is the CSS for it:

```
#layout
{
    color: White;
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 80%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#header
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #151515;
}

#footer
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    /*left: 40%;*/
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #151515;
    text-align: center;
}

#primary
{
    margin: 0 -26.4% 0 0;
    width: 75%;
}

#content
{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#nav
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#side
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 17%;
    left: 70%;
    width: 18.8%;
    text-align: left;
}

.sideFont
{
    font-size: 12px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I have the content div inside a layout div with fixed header, nav and sidebar positions
It started showing up after some css updates but I tried to backtrack my work and cant not find where it originated from and the border's length goes as far as the content shows on the page...

I'm sure it's a simple answer, thanks in advance to anyone who can slap me and say duh because I am brain farting.

Update:
The HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="header" align="center"></div>
    <div id="layout">
    <div id="primary">
        <div id="nav">
        <BR />
            <ul>
            <li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div id="content">
        content
    <div id="side" class="sideFont">
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well those borders certainly aren't from that css, so it's elsewhere. how about a jsfiddle?

Comment: I added the html and other css, cut out the content because I have them separated in pages.

Answer (score 0):

I said it was a brain fart im sorry.

It's from the layout css i saw as i pasted it into the window

```
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
```